# Is "t" a suffix?

Tags: suffixes

Is "t" a suffix ?

o*w*e ough**t**

dra*w* draugh**t**

bo*w* bigh**t**

If so, why does "w" change to "gh" ?

Comment: I am quite unclear as to what you are asking. It would seem to depend on what you mean by a "suffix". The "t" is simply part of the word. Why would it be regarded as a suffix?

Comment: @WS2 Think *keep/kept, sleep/slept, dream/dreamt*.

Comment: Notice that the spelling has nothing to do with the pronunciation; it just lags along and does whatever it feels like doing, so don't pay it any attention. So there's no reason why the W changes to GH (actually there are some, but you have to take some college courses to understand them, so we'll ignore them). As for whether it's a suffix, yes, it's a fairly rare [derivational morpheme](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf) that makes certain kinds of nouns out of certain kinds of verbs, e.g. _draw a draught_. But like all derivational morphology, it's irregular as hell.